# An error occurred while mounting static

Tags: automount, fstab

So you've edited /etc/fstab, rebooted and get some error message about mounting static.  What's static?  Turns out there's an easy answer to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1467441

User "gojan" wisely noted the following,

> "I had the same problem, everything mounted perfectly but I was
>   receiving "an error occured while mounting static" It turned out I
>   mistakenly erased # from the first line of fstab."

Somehow I'd done the same thing so the first line of /etc/fstab was the uncommented comment,

> "/etc/fstab: static file system information."

Oh, that explains why it was having an error trying to mount static.  :)